# Live Tagging while typing

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have some code for autocomplete something from my input text box with jquery and the full code is this:

```
<head>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.autocomplete.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">

  $(function(){
  var friends = [
    { value: 'Google', data: 'http://www.google.com' },
    { value: 'Facebook', data: 'http://www.facebook.com' },

  ];

  $('#autocomplete').autocomplete({
    lookup: friends,
    onSelect: function (suggestion) {
      var thehtml = '<a href="'+ suggestion.data +'">' + suggestion.value + ' </a> ' ;
      $('#tagged').html(thehtml);
    }
  });


});

  </script>
```

```
  <div id="tagged"></div>
    <form><input type="text" class="biginput" id="autocomplete"></form>
```

Now my question is how can I add more tags in #tagged without changing it with new one. And how can I put Like if I have  and between Some text and when I type @Google to start jquery from top and give me the list and then when I click to just output it next to text where I pressed @.... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use a plugin like [this one](http://aehlke.github.io/tag-it/).

In your case, the data source will be an AJAX call that will fetch results from the server, by searching tags that contain the tag string and send them to the client. There are examples of this in the docs of the plugin.

Comment: you're welcome. you can accept my answer if has been helpful. regards

Comment: I missed that I found something else on web as well and I will just edit the question..

Comment: 1. the problem you're having with autocomplete is the reason I didn't suggest that plugin, but the one I did. 2. You should not erase the old question and write a new one by editing, that's not how SO works. Instead you should post a new question.